Trying to use a Global Connected App and JWT Flow to Get an Access Token in Other Salesforce Orgs
The method that I am trying:
Create a connected app in some namespaced org, enable it to use the JWT flow. The policy is set for all users can self-authorize. I upload a certificate to this app.
In another org, let's say a scratch org I can use the following url to one-time authorize the OAuth Flow:
https://<instance_name>/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=<consumer_key of connected app>&redirect_uri=<callback url of connected app>
Hitting this link with a user in the scratch org allows me to login and one time authorize the the connected app. This also adds it to the OAuth usage in the scratch org.
Next I generate a JWT token using the Crypto class in Apex and the private key stored in a CMT. I can't store the cert in this scratch org for specific reasons so I have to generate the JWT token without the JWT salesforce class. The claims map in the JWT token uses the following values:

'iss' : consumer key of connected app.
'sub' : username of the user that did the one time authorization.
'aud' :https://test.salesforce.com (scratch org instance url doesn't work here and it gives me an invalid audience if I don't use this).
'exp': 5 mins after current time.

This successfully generates the JWT token. I use the following request to get an access token:
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://<instance_name>.com/services/oauth2/token');  
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

// Set the body with grant_type and assertion (the JWT)
String body = 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' +
'&assertion=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(jwt, 'UTF-8');
req.setBody(body);

Http http = new Http();

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

This results in the following error:
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved this consumer"}.
This is despite the user I specify in the 'sub' value having one time authorized the OAuth flow with the link I mentioned above. The only thing that seems to work is installing the global connected app in the scratch org from the OAuth Usage settings and then setting the policy to pre-approve the profile of that same user. This then allows me to get an access token when I make the request. But I don't want to install the app in the scratch org + it doesn't seem necessary to make this flow work.
The overall idea is that I'm enabling the scratch org and potentially separate orgs entirely to use the same connected app definition to drive this JWT flow and get an access token when needed in apex. This entire flow is fairly new to me so would love some help on if I'm approaching this the wrong way or it doesn't make sense.
